# Правомерна ли фраза с деепричастным оборотом

Tags: согласование

Фраза записана на слух, читалась диктором с листа. Неполная, но суть передаёт.

> Поднимая эти вопросы, нужна серьёзная аналитика.

Допустимо ли такое согласование в предложении?

Answer (score 3):

Предложение некорректно.

**Из Розенталя:**

"Действие, обозначаемое деепричастием (деепричастным оборотом), относится, как правило, к подлежащему данного предложения".

Но здесь этого нет. Под исключения предложение тоже не подходит, так как **нет глагольной формы**, к которой можно отнести деепричастный оборот.

"Не отвечает норме употребление деепричастного оборота в страдательной конструкции, так как производитель действия, выраженного сказуемым, и производитель действия, выраженного деепричастием, не совпадают".

http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/69.htm

Вариант редактирования: "***Для постановки вопросов*** о неуглеродной экономике или запрете тех или иных производств нужна очень серьезная аналитика, нужно глубоко изучить эти процессы как на научном уровне, так и с четким предвидением и пониманием экономических последствий  от принятых решений, — уверен Виктор Вексельберг, председатель Совета директор фонда "Сколково".

https://moskva.bezformata.com/listnews/forum-v-davose-dal-pochuvstvovat/81014295/

Как я понимаю, это запись устных ответов на вопросы журналистов. Чтобы в таких условиях корректно строить предложения с деепричастными оборотами, надо иметь **четкие знания о правильности их употребления** и уметь оперативно контролировать свою речь в этом плане.

Comment: Но Резенталь же пишет "*как правило*", а не всегда. Значит, бывают исключения.

Comment: Исключения перечислены в этой же теме, но в любом случае нужна глагольная форма.  Деепричастие обозначает добавочное действие, которое поясняет основное действие, выраженное глаголом-сказуемым. Нет глагола - не должно быть и деепричастия

Answer (score 1):

Такое допустимо лишь в устной речи как упрощение, но в исходном виде так записать нельзя, поскольку это означало бы, что "эти вопросы поднимает аналитика, которая нужна". Полная форма сказанного могла быть такой:

> Поднимая эти вопросы, *скажу следующее:* нужна серьёзная аналитика.

Чтобы записать такую речь в упрощённом варианте, нужно пунктуационно обозначить пропущенное (опущен основной глагол - этому должна и пауза при чтении соответствовать), например при помощи тире или двоеточия:

> Поднимая эти вопросы: нужна серьёзная аналитика.

Если же смысл был в том, что "при поднятии вопросов нужна аналитика", то передать его не удалось - тогда имела место *речевая ошибка*.

Answer (score 1):

Так не корректно. Звучит очень плохо. Что-то оно вообще не согласуется.

Здесь явно заменили придаточное с "*если*":
*Если поднимать эти вопросы, нужна серьёзная аналитика.*
Это распространённая ошибка — ещё, например, замена придаточного будущего времени на деепричастный оборот:
*Приехав [когда приеду] в город своего детства, я обязательно встречусь со школьными друзьями и моей первой учительницей.*